# Generate a network with predefined edge lengths distribution

Tags: python, matlab, networking, graph, distribution

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm that would allow me to generate a regular graph with degree D=3 and log-normal distribution of edges lengths (distances between nodes).

I know there are couple ways to generate network with predefined degree distribution (explained [here](http://mathinsight.org/generating_networks_desired_degree_distribution) for example), but can't find a way to get a predefined lengths distribution.

(Matlalb or Python)

Comment: Maybe check out [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generators.html)

Comment: what do you mean by *log-normal distribution of edges lengths* ? I don't get it

Comment: networkx doesn't have this feature, as to my knowledge.

Comment: log normal http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution where Y=ln(X) , Y- frequency, X - lengths